# EF Core 8 : getting grand children from grandparent

Tags: entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, relationship, eager-loading

I am writing a an application which contains model classes with the following navigation properties

```
TestReport => Students => ClassSchedule => Tests
```

The relationship is `one-to-many` towards right side of every entity. I am using EF Core 8.0.

The `TestReports` is a master table whose details are in the `ReportDetails` table. I shall fetch the student's tests from the `Tests` table and store their grades in the `ReportDetails` table.

I want to get a list of `Tests` provided with the `TestReportId`.

What I am trying to do is get `StudentId` from `TestReports` and then get all the tests of that student from `Tests` table.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information, but query should be something like this:

```cs
var query = 
    from r in context.TestReports
    from st in r.Students
    from t in st.ClassSchedule.Tests
    where t.Id == reportId
    select t;
```